# Messenger Extensions in Vue.js and using its data as a global variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to use [Messenger's Extension SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions) with Vue.js. I'm relatively new to Vue.js and haven't used any js framework before stumbling upon Vue.

I've thought about (and tried) adding the SDK code (see link above, step 2) to my App.vue site that holds my `router-view`. I've also tried including the script to my index.html which holds the `div` that I add Vue to.

The goal is to be able to include the SDK to all of my pages, eventually have a callback that's triggered when the SDK is done loading (see link above, step 3), and finally be able to use the SDKs function on all of my views (for example and most important, `MessengerExtensions.getContext(app_id, success, error)`).

How can I make this work? Thanks,

Comment: Did you make a comment earlier? Was going to reply but got side tracked with a call. All working?

Comment: @CraigvanTonder yes I struggled for a while there but it appeared to be a simple mistake on my end. I managed to get it working. How would I go ahead with creating a ”global variable” with data from the getContext function that is set once extAsyncInit is triggered?

Comment: Cool am glad, check out Vuex as it solves that aspect of things.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder great thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So based on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions and https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/getting-started.html you could likely do something like:

```
const app = new Vue({
  router,
  created() {
    return (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Then in your App.vue:

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    window.extAsyncInit = function() {
      // the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading 
    };
  }
}
```